# How to edit content within a tag once it's extracted?

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a program that extracts game titles and prices of games under the "New and Trending" column on https://store.steampowered.com/. So far I have it so the titles and prices are printed vertically as separate lists.

The prices print like so:

```
$11.99
$9.99
$23.99
$34.99
Free To Play
$24.99
$59.99
Free To Play
$13.49
$19.99
```

What I want to do take any price with the string "Free To Play" and replace it with the string "$0.00" so when  I export to a csv it looks more consistent. I've tried using the `replace_with()` function through BeautifulSoup, but it didn't work out for me.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/'
uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

title_containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"tab_item_name"}, limit=10)
price_containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"discount_final_price"}, limit=10)
for titles in title_containers:
    print(titles.get_text())
for prices in price_containers:
    print(prices.get_text())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this doesn't use beautifulsoup, you can simply

```
...
for prices in price_containers:
    print(prices.get_text().replace('Free To Play', '$0.00'))
```

Comment: Well clearly I forgot to K.I.S.S. Thanks for the answer. :)